# Collecting Information with static hosting?

Tags: javascript, mysql, html

I have a query with regard to HTML and mySQL. I wan't to add a small element of functionality to a static website which will take the e-mail addresses of fans and add it to a contacts table. Is there any way to do this without paying for php or aspx hosting? I.E. Can you do it via HTML or can you do it with javascript without incurring the Hosting costs? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'm working on it! what is the deadline? I'll do it for you!

Comment: I'm sure when he said 'can you do it' he meant 'can one do it' as in 'can it be done'.

Comment: There are A LOT of free PHP hosting. It's just a matter of putting some effort in looking for them.

Comment: In the world of web hosting, you get what you pay for holds very true.  Don't try to cut corners when you can get cheapo-shared hosting for like $4/mo!

Comment: openshift works just fine, as does google appengine.

Comment: @xbonez. I'm sure he did, but it's still a poor question...

Comment: I'm only building a small site for a young band and was just wondering if it was possible to take fan's emails information without php or aspx that I didn't know about. But if there's not i'll leave it static. No worries thanks for the responses I'll just leave it out. @Joseph the Dreamer the band have a 1 year free hosting via a government grant but the php module costs €6.95 with the partner company giving the grant per month for their php module! so they can't use the free php sites!!   Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

http://mailchimp.com/features/

I can't say if the free version is any good but it might be worth looking into.

Basically, you make a form on your site which passes the email address to their site and they maintain the list of email addresses. You can then log in and see everyone who has signed up and send out emails to them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with jquery with json but the security will be very fragile someone told me once about spoof they can see al your code and all your function calls